# return filtred list of java objects based on property value

Tags: java

Let's suppose that i have an Array of objects (Payment) :

```
listPayments=[Payment(type='check', amount=25),Payment(type='cash', amount=20),Payment(type='check', amount=25),Payment(type='cash', amount=20)]
```

i want to get an array that contains objects with amount sum based on payment type like so :

```
filtredList = [Payment(type='check', amount=50),Payment(type='cash', amount=40)]
```

But ***i don't want to hard code the type*** because i can have multiple payment types, can you help me to find a generic way to do this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this if you are using java 8 or greater:

```java
listOfPayment.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
Payment::getType, 
Collectors.summarizingLong(Payment::getAmount)))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> new Payment(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getSum()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marco you saved my day ^^

Answer (score 1):

Since the solution with streams is already provided by Marco, here's the good old iterative method of doing it:

```java
Map<String, Integer> typeToSum = new HashMap<>();
for (Payment payment : payments) {
  String type = payment.getType();
  int amount = payment.getAmount();
  int newSum = typeToSum.getOrDefault(type, 0) + amount;
  typeToSum.put(type, newSum);
}

List<Payment> result = new ArrayList<>(typeToSum.size());
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : typeToSum.entrySet()) {
  Payment payment = new Payment(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
  result.add(payment);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Utku, it is so helpful actually i have two useful solutions ^^

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it..

```
static Map<String, Integer> paymentMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

private static Payment[] getFilterdPayments() {
    Payment[] listPayments = new Payment[] { new Payment("check", 25), new Payment("cash", 20),
            new Payment("check", 25), new Payment("cash", 20) };
    for (Payment payment : listPayments) {
        addValueToMap(payment.getType(), payment.getValue());
    }

    List<Payment> filteredlist=new ArrayList<Payment>();
    for (String type : paymentMap.keySet()) {
        filteredlist.add(new Payment(type, paymentMap.get(type)));
    }
    
    return (Payment[]) filteredlist.toArray(new Payment[0]);
}

private static void addValueToMap(String key, int value) {
    if(paymentMap.containsKey(key)) {
        paymentMap.put(key, value+paymentMap.get(key));
    }
    else {
        paymentMap.put(key, value);
    }
}`
```

Comment: Thank you Shubham for your answer but i wanted a generic solution without hard coded values, thaks a lot.

Comment: Hi, @noussair- May I know where did I hardcode the values.? If you mean below line:
`Payment[] listPayments = new Payment[] { new Payment("check", 25), new Payment("cash", 20),
            new Payment("check", 25), new Payment("cash", 20) }; `
 I have just declared the test data that you yourself provided. Basically its your **input**,  not part of the code. We can remove that and we still have a working solution.